# Eval_Metrics not recognized/invalid in AWS XGBoost model

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, xgboost, amazon-sagemaker

```
xgb.set_hyperparameters(objective='binary:logistic',num_round=100)
xgb.fit({'train': s3_input_train})

...


from sagemaker.tuner import IntegerParameter, CategoricalParameter, ContinuousParameter, HyperparameterTuner
hyperparameter_ranges = {'eta': ContinuousParameter(0, 1),
                         'min_child_weight': ContinuousParameter(1, 10),
                         'alpha': ContinuousParameter(0, 2),
                         'max_depth': IntegerParameter(1, 10),
                         'num_round': IntegerParameter(1, 300),
                        'gamma': ContinuousParameter(0, 5),
                        'lambda': ContinuousParameter(0, 1000),
                        'max_delta_step':IntegerParameter(1, 10),
                        'colsample_bylevel':ContinuousParameter(0.1, 1),
                        'colsample_bytree':ContinuousParameter(0.5, 1),
                        'subsample':ContinuousParameter(0.5, 1)}


objective_metric_name = 'validation:aucpr'

tuner = HyperparameterTuner(xgb,
                            objective_metric_name,
                            hyperparameter_ranges,
                            max_jobs=50,
                            max_parallel_jobs=3)

tuner.fit({'train': s3_input_train, 'validation': s3_input_val}, include_cls_metadata=False, wait=False)
```

Returns the error:

```
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the CreateHyperParameterTuningJob operation: The objective metric for the hyperparameter tuning job, [validation:aucpr], isn’t valid for the [811284229777.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/xgboost:latest] algorithm. Choose a valid objective metric.
```

The same applies when replacing aucpr with f1 and logloss. They are clearly defined as evaluation metrics in the documentation for classification purposes. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/xgboost-tuning.html

What can I do to allow the f1, aucpr and logloss evaluation metrics?

Answer (score 0):

While `validation:auc`, `validation:f1` and `validation:logloss` are indeed Evaluation Metrics they are not Tunable XGBoost Hyperparameters.

Please see the [table below](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/xgboost-tuning.html#xgboost-tunable-hyperparameters) for the Tunable Hyperparameters

Your code is trying to set the `objective metric` as one which is not supported.

Evaluation metrics would be input as part of the hyperparamaters:

For example,

```
xgb.set_hyperparameters(
    eval_metric="auc",
    objective="binary:logistic",
    num_round=10,
    rate_drop=0.3,
    tweedie_variance_power=1.4,
)
```

From the doc you shared:

```
a learning objective function to optimize during model training

an eval_metric to use to evaluate model performance during validation
```

Comment: Setting eval_metric="f1" is still invalid. The error states that it is not an option.

Comment: What container (version) are you making use of ?

Comment: 811284229777.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/xgboost:latest

Comment: I was able to set the `objective_metric_name = 'validation:aucpr'` and 
`eval_metric="f1"` using `'683313688378.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/sagemaker-xgboost:0.90-1-cpu-py3'`